# ¿Hay manera de 'emular' el workspace de MatLab en el explorador de variables de Spyder (Python)?

Tags: python, matlab

Tengo encomendada la misión de migrar código de MatLab a Python. El script de Matlab es para una aplicación de física de materiales que hace algunas simulaciones. Mi primer gran conflicto es que hace uso de muchísimas variables y muchos Scripts sub-alternos hacen uso constante de estas variables, y a su vez estos sub-Scripts generan otras tantas variables que guardan valores e información importante. Hasta donde sé, Python solo pude trabajar con variables declaradas en un mismo script o archivo .py, y estar llamando y devolviendo todas las variables que requiere cada script se vuelve tedioso y poco práctico. Pensaba en generar archivos de alguna extensión para guardar esta información pero aún así sigue el problema de llamar las varibales en específico que sean requeridas (que pueden llegar a ser muchas).
¿Alguien conoce alguna forma de almacenar variables en el explorador de Spyder que otros scripts puedan reconocer y hacer uso de estas sin necesidad de estarlas declarando?
Si tienen otros métodos estaré interesado en leerlos. Si requieren más detalle sobre lo que intento hacer con gusto explicaré más a fondo).

Comment: Nop, es falso que solo se pueda hacer uso de variables declaradas en un archivo. Si puedes hacer uso de variables externas si es que importas otro archivo

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar variables en archivos **.mat** estos son generados en MATLAB y existe una librería para python que permite leer y editar archivos **.mat**. Te recomiendo que investigues eso.